# Target subdomain and host domain with URL rewrite module

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Below I have a rule that works great with subdomains of example.com, but I need to use https://example.com (example.com) now.  The {C:1} was always the subdomain, but now that I dont have a subdomain it needs to be "other".  Is there a way to set a default if the {C:1} is null or empty to "other" and match on the host name without subdomain.

```
<rule name="Apple Icon Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(apple-touch-icon.*?)(?:-precomposed)?(.png)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).example.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/assets/sports/{C:1}/icons/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite can only handle the trivial cases. If you need more control over the behaviors, implement your own IIS module, or simply implement such logic in your own web app.

Comment: Id have to disagree.  I have done some complex stuff in URL Rewrite module, but there isnt the best documentation on what I can and cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add one additional rule, which will catch only exmple.com domain like that:

```
<rule name="Apple Icon Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(apple-touch-icon.*?)(?:-precomposed)?(.png)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/assets/sports/other/icons/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing.